# problem with source canonical dist

Tags: updates

I m ubuntu 12.04 upgraded to 13.0 My problem is when I want to update I have a message:

```
W: Impossible de récupérer http://archive.canonical.com/raring/dists/precise/partner/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
```

Really my problem is the font Augie (emerald package ) doesn't much in texlive2013.iso that I intalled manually (excuse my English).

Whats wrong please?

Comment: Please edit your question to show us the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list`. And tell us the output of `lsb_release -a`.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that update-manager is heavily buggy, especially in non-English environment

try updating using this command:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

i'm not sure it's gonna work, but it will give us more info

and the content of the file /etc/apt/sources.list may help too

Comment: This command will very probably not helpful in any way - not without knowing where he is now with his system.